# tabs width and git - force git convert automatically on commit

Tags: git

I was wondering if it's possible to create a project-specific before-commit hook.

For example, I have a shared project on github. Let's call it "tab-crazy".

Then I create a file called `.git-pre-commit-hook` with something like this inside it:

```
sed 's/\t/ /g'
```

And then, in every commit, git will run this hook in what is changed, avoiding tab-crazy developers to do crap with tab-width config.

Is something like this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those developers will need the hook on *their* systems. And your hook won't be able to modify the files in any clean way - but it can simply reject the commit and tell them to fix their mess.

Comment: Yeah, but my hypothetical solution would be cool.

Comment: Until it silently mangled the whitespace in some quoted string, or text file, or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, git has [hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) like this.

As ThiefMaster says, you can't *modify* the code about to be committed, but you can check it and reject the commit.